# Powershell: parametersets, require one or the other

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Consider this Cmdlet (usings removed):

```
public class Foo : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ParameterSetName = "Foo"]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ParameterSetName = "Bar"]
    public string B { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ParameterSetName = "Bar"]
    public string C { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
         /* magic goes here */
    }
}
```

Now the way you can execute this Cmdlet is as follows:

```
# like this
Foo

# or
Foo -A "test"

# or
Foo -B "test" -C "test"
```

Having and A and B doesn't work, neither does only using B (requires C).

So that's fine, however I want to prevent that you can execute the Cmdlet by just typing `Foo`, now I can check that in code, but since Powershell is so awesome, is there a way to enforce this through the runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may instruct PowerShell to default to a named parameter set, by way of the `DefaultParameterSetName` property of the `CmdletAttribute` attribute:

```
[Cmdlet("Foo", "Bar", DefaultParameterSetName = "Foo")]
public class Foo : Cmdlet
{
   // ...
}
```